# How to Map an object contains a List with Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

Given the Source class as defined below:

```
class Source{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Phone> phones;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and the Phone class as defined below:

```
class Phone{
        private Long id;
        private String phoneNumber;
        // getters and setters
    }
```

and the Target class as defined below:

```
class Target{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Long> idsPhones;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I have an interface is:

```
@Mapper
interface MyMapper{
    Target toTarget(Source source);
    Source toSource(Target target);
}
```

How can I map the List of Phones from the Source class to a List of idsPhones in the Target Class and vice versa?

Comment: What is the structure of the Phone class? What does idsPhone represent? How are they related? What have you tried so far?

The question needs more details.

Comment: Hi @archilius , the phone class has this structure: class Phone{ private Long id, private String  phoneNumber}

Comment: Add this as an edit in the question and answer the other questions I asked. Without enough details, nobody will be able to help you

Comment: Have you considered using [orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to help MapStruct a bit by telling how to map from `Phone` into `Long`. And the reverse as well.

Your mapper needs to look something like:

```
@Mapper(uses = PhoneRepository.class)
interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "idsPhones", source = "phones")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    @InheritInverseMapping
    Source toSource(Target target);

    default Long fromPhone(Phone phone) {
        return phone.getId();
    }
}
```

If your `PhoneRepository` contains a method that accepts a `Long` and returns `Phone` then MapStruct will automatically know what to do and invoke that method.